# laravel eloquent union, join 2 columns in the same table

Tags: laravel, union

I have the following columns in the same table

```
Column 1
--------
1

2

3

Column 2
--------
4

5

6
```

I want it to be displayed like

```
Columns
--------
1

2

3

4

5

6
```

Comment: And your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`unionAll`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#unions)

```
$first = DB::table('yourTable')
->select('column1 as res');

$result  = DB::table('yourTable')
            ->select('column2 as res')
            ->unionAll($first)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Union of your data by taking out separately and merge it after. You can use **union()** as well as **merge()**, One thing to mention is that both data must have same skelton means structure.

```
 use DB;

 public function yourFunction(){
     $data_1 = DB::table('table_name')->get();
     $data_2 = DB::table('table_name')->get();
     //your final data
     $final_data = $data_1->union($data_2);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming values are in the same row:

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')->select('column1', 'column2')->get();
$c = count($data);
if ($c) {
    $col1 = [];
    $col2 = [];
    foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
        $col1[] = $d->column1;
        $col2[$c + $k] = $d->column2;
    }
    $result = array_merge($col1, $col2);

    foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo $value."\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "No data in table.";
}
```